# Does rust have steady clock?

Tags: rust

Is there a Rust equivalent of C++'s [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock)? (emphasis on **steady**)

> The time points of this clock cannot decrease as physical time moves
> forward and the **time between ticks of this clock is constant**.

[`std::time::Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html) apparently doesn't fit:

> ... instants are not guaranteed to be steady. In other words, **each
> tick of the underlying clock might not be the same length** (e.g. some
> seconds may be longer than others). An instant may jump forwards or
> experience time dilation (slow down or speed up) ...

Comment: These are the same ideas expressed using different words. In both cases, the actual perceived time between ticks _might_ not be even. That is because, in both cases, the time is _guaranteed_ to increase.

Comment: @PeterHall They are not the same. The documentation of `Instant` even explicitly says that the clock is not guaranteed to be steady, while `steady_clock` is. However, I'm not sure it's even possible to have a steady clock on every platform. On Linux, you can get a steady clock using `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...)`, which is used by `Instant` under the hood. I don't know about other platforms, and I have some doubts this can be correctly implemented on every platform for C++.

Comment: I don't even know what "time between ticks of this clock is constant" means. I assume up to some resolution, right? Otherwise this claim is meaningless. I think that C++ documentation is misleading. In particular I don't see any such guarantee in Linux docs.

Comment: `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is based on the hardware clock, but includes speed adjustments by NTP, so it's kind of the closest a normal computer can get to the real elapsed time since some unspecified point in the past, and also the closest it can get to a steady clock.

Comment: Btw, I've just checked the source code. Both C++'s steady_clock and Rust's Interval literally use the same syscalls under the hood. For both Unix and Windows. So at least one of the docs is incorrect. And these are the same clocks.

Comment: @freakish You can probably post that as an answer.

Comment: "time between ticks of this clock is constant" is wishful thinking. There is no such thing in the physical universe.

Comment: @SvenMarnach check `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`

Comment: @C.M. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` is basically the same as `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, but without the NTP adjustments, so it will be less steady.

Comment: @freakish No, it doesn't follow that one of the docs is incorrect just because the two are the implementation is the same on two platforms. One of the countless other platforms supported by Rust could have a clock implementation that isn't steady.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Afaik, NTP adjustments are to keep clock in sync with real time. For steadiness you just need every tick to be of same duration (no need to sync with external clock). In this sense using NTP adjustments makes it less steady, not the other way around.

Comment: @C.M. This is not true. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` runs at the rate of the hardware clock, which is usually based on a crystal oscillator. As such, it is dependent on environment conditions, it will run on slightly different speeds based on temperature, so as the machine heats up, its rate will change. NTP will not only detect clock drift and correct the system time based on that, it also detects differences in the clock _rate_ and then adjusts the rate based on this data. This information ultimately comes from timeservers with atomic clocks, so you will end up with a steadier clock rate.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Huh... I didn't know that. But for purposes of measuring time given code took to execute -- it is "steady" in a sense that it will return correct number of ticks (regardless of temp), simply because clock that drives CPU will slow down/speed as well (hopefully at the same rate). I.e. from perspective of measuring code execution speed (on the same CPU) it is steady. Am I wrong?

Comment: Both `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` and `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` are independent of the CPU clock. Apart from that, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach I want to measure how long it takes to execute a function. Let say I executed it twice and in both cases initial state of the system (CPU, caches, etc) is exactly the same -- I would expect execution time (measured in CPU ticks) will be the same. Is there such clock that is guaranteed to produce same duration value for both of those tests? (assume no interference from OS context switching, etc)

Comment: @C.M. I don't think there is, since the system is usually too complex. First, there usually _is_ interference from the OS, IRQ handlers etc, and it's next to impossible to avoid that. Memory timing is subject to some noise. The CPU clock rate itself might not be entirely steady. There are just too many factors, including physical ones. Moreover, it's not really possible to have the system in the same state twice. If you want something deterministic, you might want to look into callgrind, but it's not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Afaik, it is "somewhat possible" -- in Linux you could set aside a CPU, it will be ignored by OS/etc, use it to run your code (which will use related instructions to invalidate CPU cache(s)). But yes, if CPU can't guarantee that same command always takes same number of CPU cycles (assuming same starting state) -- then it is pointless... You have to use averaging over multiple test runs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are few facts that I've gathered:

1. gcc implements steady_clock::now() via clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...) syscall;
2. llvm's libc++ implements steady_clock::now() via clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, ...) syscall for Unix. Under Windows it implements via QueryPerformanceCounter(...);
3. Rust's Interval utilizes clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...) under Unix and QueryPerformanceCounter(...) under Windows as well;

I didn't check other platforms, but since Rust uses llvm under the hood, it is likely it utilizes the same syscalls. So Rust's Interval and C++ steady_clock implementations use the exact same syscalls, at least for gcc and llvm.

Moreover the Unix's clock_gettime() syscall is not guaranteed to have a steady rate (or at least I couldn't find such guarantee), and so such C++ guarantee is puzzling. Furthermore if we look at the actual C++ standard, it says something a bit different:

> 23.17.7.2 Class steady_clock
>
> 1. Objects of class steady_clock represent clocks for which values of time_point never decrease as physical
>    time advances and for which values of time_point advance at a steady rate relative to real time. That is, the clock may not be adjusted.

For me it sounds like "steady rate" is more about "the clock cannot be adjusted" rather than a guarantee that the time between ticks is constant. This term "steady rate" sounds fuzzy for me. But, I suppose it is a matter of interpretation.

Either way, both Rust and C++ implement these clocks in the same way, and that is unlikely to change. I suppose that the truth is somewhere in between: C++'s guarantee is impossible to be true (unless the time is constant up to some precision), while Rust's warning is probably not as bad as it sounds.

**EDIT:** some x86 cpus, in fact all Intel cpus starting with Pentium 4, have this feature called "constant TSC". According to [the wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter#Use) it can be accessed through clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, ...) on Unix systems, and it is built into QueryPerformanceCounter on Windows. This "clock" ticks at cpu speed independent way, but how close it is to "constant rate" is not clear (at least for me). Probably quite close. Of course you'd need to do a direct syscall on Unix, and it is limited to x86 arch only. Also does not seem to tick while the system is suspended. I don't know if other archs have similar thing.

Comment: Looks like latest CPUs have [constant TSC](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) (aka invariant TSC) accessible on Linux via [`clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html). On Win default mechanism (`QueryPerformanceCounter()`) uses it automatically (if available). So, at least on some hardware steadiness guarantee seems achievable (unless "system was suspended" -- not sure what it means, tbh).

Comment: `The invariant TSC will run at a constant rate in all ACPI P-, C-. and T-states.` I.e. (with exception of sleeping) `invariant TSC` actually runs independently from CPU speed. And not running while sleeping is actually correct thing to do wrt measuring how long given piece of code runs for.

Comment: Yeah, this "constant TSC" thing looks promising. However neither Rust nor C++ takes advantage of that, probably because of portability issue. Also "suspended system" probably means exactly what it says, e.g. when you close a laptop.

Comment: They do take advantage of that on Windows...

Comment: Yeah, I thought about Unix only, my bad.

Comment: Do you want to update your answer with this info? It is kind of important... In fact, Rust docs need to be updated with smth like "on these platforms std::time::Instant is steady if invariant TSC is available" (and note about sleeping, VM suspension, etc)

Comment: Yeah, I will do that a bit later (I'm traveling at the moment). Btw "constant ticks" is a simplification. This cannot be understood literally, due to physical (quantum) limitations of measuring small time intervals (not to mention relativistic effects). This should be always understood as up to some precision. Perhaps extremely small, but still.

Comment: For me it is enough if ticks are "constant" in abstract "execution machine" sense (where code technically executes), not in context of some physical theory (regardless how popular it is now -- it always eventually gets replaced by another one ;) )

Comment: Unless you happen to be a software developer for the GPS. ;)

Comment: [From here](https://forums.guru3d.com/threads/a-bit-detailed-info-on-intel-time-stamp-counter-tsc.433977/): `The invariant TSC is based on the invariant timekeeping hardware (called Always Running Timer or ART), that runs at the core crystal clock frequency.` Looks like steadiness is achieved via dedicated hardware.

Comment: "software developer for the GPS" - How well `execution machine` time maps to `real-world` time doesn't concern 99.9999% of developers. :)

Comment: Also see [Other Architectures](https://handwiki.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter#Other_architectures).

Comment: On Linux, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is the time of the hardware clock with the rate adjusted based on the NTP data, which effectively gives you a clock that is almost as good as the atomic clock in the time server you get the NTP data from. While this is not explicitly documented as "steady", it is documented as "useful for measuring short time intervals accurately" and "the monotonic time since some unspecified starting point". Since physical time is steady, you can only measure short time intervals accurately with a steady clock.

Comment: If you want a steady clock, then `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` is strictly worse. Without the NTP adjustments, you get the raw rate of the hardware clock, which is subject to all the limitations of crystal oscillators.